# How to display this file structure array in tree structure

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Here is my array output. I want to display this array in tree structure. 
I am using dynatree for display files and folder

```
array (size=27)
   0 => string 'Chrysanthemum.jpg' (length=17)
   1 => string 'Chrysanthemum_1.jpg' (length=19)
   2 => string 'Desert.jpg' (length=10)
  'mst146' => 
       array (size=1)
             0 => string 'test123.txt' (length=11)
   't124' => 
       array (size=1)
             0 => string 'Jellyfish_2.jpg' (length=15)
   'test' => 
       array (size=9)
             0 => string 'Chrysanthemum.jpg' (length=17)
             1 => string 'Desert.jpg' (length=10)
```

I want to output like this

```
Chrysanthemum.jpg
Chrysanthemum_1.jpg
Desert.jpg
mst146
 test123.txt
t124
 Jellyfish_2
test
 Chrysanthemum.jpg
 Desert.jpg
```

Comment: Why would two `Jellyfish2` items by listed at `t124
 Jellyfish_2
    Jellyfish_2` ?

Comment: make output just as you input array. It is not clear.

Comment: it is just example dude just give me code for display like this @guest271314

Comment: okay cleared now u can help me @Jitendra

Comment: @KevinPatel _"I want to output like this"_ Where should output be displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to create a series of lists so you could try something like this.

```
<div id="tree">
   <ul>
   <?php foreach($array as $key => $first_level){ ?>
       <?php if(is_array($first_level)) { ?>
            <li class="folder"> <?php echo $key; ?>
                <ul>
                   <?php foreach($first_level as $second_level){ ?>
                      <li> <?php echo $second_level; ?>
                   <?php } ?>
                </ul>
       <?php }else{ ?>
           <li> <?php echo $first_level; ?>
       <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/

Comment: can u add in my code my array name is $files @Ethan22